# Bootstrap 3 Navbar - problem with navbar-header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've built this Navbar (with Bootstrap 3) which is done to styling requirements.
After building it, and being told it tested fine (and it was deployed to production) someone realised that the Navbar header (the logo) isn't a clickable link.
[image]

I realised that's because i had set a CSS style `height:0` for the navbar-header class.
My problem is, everything ive tried to do to fix it (like obviously removing the height:0) then breaks the layout.

Also - the issue with the navbar-header class only exists on Desktop or L \ XL screens sizes.
When the nav is collapsed (mobile \ tablet) then the navbar-header logo is a clickable link as expected.

Can anyone suggest some hacky CSS to fix this?
Please note - i have changed the breakpoint for when the nav collapses, but that's not in this code.

Rather than pasting the code, i created a fiddle for it;

https://jsfiddle.net/BlissSol/8s6xn2vt/3/

Edit - for those that don't see an issue, expand the width of the view in the fiddle so its at least 1222px wide.
So on a 1920x1080 screen, the fiddle ends up looking something like this:
[image]
If the view is smaller than this, you'll see that the logo is fine to click on.

Here's the CSS code:

```
<style>
        html {
            font-size: initial;
            padding: initial;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 180px;
        }
       

        .container-fluid {
            max-width: 1440px;
        }

        .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown > .dropdown-data-toggle:active {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .drop-nav {
            margin-top: 3px;
        }

        .fa-person {
            line-height: 0.5em !important;
        }
         
        body {
             font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
        }
        
        /* NEW */
        .ceda-nav-border {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e11837;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: #252932;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        .nav-link { 
            padding-left: 1.25rem;
            padding-right: 1.25rem;
            font-size: .875rem;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 2rem;
            color: #252932;
        }

        .padding-menu-top {
            padding-top: .30rem;
            padding-bottom: .30rem;
        }

        .padding-menu-bottom {
            padding-top: .20rem;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
            color: #252932;
        }

        .navbar-nav > li > a {
            line-height: 22px;
        }

        .li .nav-item {
            font-size: .875rem;
            color: #000;
            line-height: 2rem;
        }

        .dropdown-item {
            color:#252932;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%; 
            white-space: nowrap;
            background-color: transparent;
            padding: 1.25rem 1.5rem;
        }

        .dropdown-divider {
            margin-bottom: .75rem !important;
            margin-top: .75rem !important;
            background-color: transparent !important;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: .875rem;
        }

        .navbar-header {
            height: 0px;
        }

        .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover:before {
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            background-color: rgba(225,24,55,1);
            color: #e11837;
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 7px;
        }

        .dropdown-menu {
            border-top: 4px solid #e11837 !important;
            /* margin-top: 14px !important; */
            padding: .5rem 0;
            margin: .125rem 0 0;
            min-width: 10rem;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 1000;
            display: none;
            font-size: 1rem;
            border-radius: 0 !important;
        }

        .top-menu {
            /* margins for dropdown-menu */
            margin-top: -3px !important;
        }

        .bottom-menu {
            /* margins for dropdown-menu */
            margin-top: 14px !important;
        }

        .align-middle {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .w-105 {
            width: 105%;
        }

        .small-row {
            height: 33px;
        }

        .large-row {
            height: 55px;
        }

        .w-100 {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .w-110 {
            width: 110%;
        }

        .w-120 {
            width: 120%;
        }

        .w-130 {
            width: 130%;
        }

        .w-175 {
            width: 175%;
        }

        .w-185 {
            width: 185%;
        }

        .pb-4 {
            padding-bottom: 4px;
        }

        .pb-5 {
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .pt-2 {
            padding-top: .5rem;
        }

        .pl-2 {
            padding-left: .5rem;
        }

        .pr-2 {
            padding-right: .5rem;
        }

        .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-top-menu {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-toggle{
            border: none;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
            background-color: black;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .join-ceda, .support-ceda {
            padding-right: 7px;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
            color:#000 !important;
        }

        .breadcrumb > li a {
            color: black;
        }

        .footer {
            position: relative !important;
        }

        @media (max-width: 1199px) {
            .navbar-header {
                float: none;
            }
            .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
                float: none !important;
            }
            .navbar-toggle {
                display: block;
            }
            .navbar-collapse {
                border-top: 1px solid transparent;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
            }
            .navbar-collapse.collapse {
                 display: none!important; 
            } 
            .collapse.in{
                display:block !important;
            }
            .navbar-nav {
                float: none!important;
                margin-top: 7.5px;
            }
            .navbar-nav>li>a {
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .navbar-nav>li {
                float: none;
            }
            .navbar-brand {
                padding: 10px 25px;
            }
            .ceda-logo {
                max-width: 110px;
            }

            .navbar-collapse {
                margin-top: 50px;
            }

            .navbar-nav {
                margin: 0px;
            }
            .cedaMenuCarot {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                right: 12px;
                top: 13px;
            }
            .nav-item {
                padding-left: .75rem;
                padding-right: .75rem;
            }
           
            .dropdown-menu {
                white-space: normal;
                border: 0 !important;
                border-radius: 0 !important;
                box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 18%);
                margin-top: 4px !important;
                padding: .5rem 0;
            }
            .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
                position: static;
                float: none;
            }
            .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
                color: #252932;
                background-color: #fff;
            }
        }
        
    </style>
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #fff;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-md navbar-fixed-top ceda-nav-border">
      <div class="container-fluid clearfix">
        
            <!-- Brand/logo -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img class="ceda-logo" src="https://events.ceda.com.au/App_Themes/CEDA2020/ceda-logo.png" alt="CEDA Logo">
                </a>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Large screen Navbar -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <div class="row visible-lg-block">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-12 small-row align-middle">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav float-none pull-right list-unstyled ceda-nav-border">
                            <li class="nav-item padding-menu-top" style="background-color: #A5BB29;">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="i-ceda.svg" class="join-ceda">Join CEDA</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown padding-menu-top">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg pr-2 pl-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Sign in</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu top-menu w-185" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My details</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My event registrations</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My support cases</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My invoices</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My corporate tables</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Company profile</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Company invoices</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Company staff details</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Company membership</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">company corporate tables</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item padding-menu-top">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="i-support.svg" class="support-ceda">Support us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item padding-menu-top">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg pr-2 pl-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contact</a>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-12 large-row align-middle">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav float-none pull-right list-unstyled">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown padding-menu-bottom">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/research-and-policy">Research and policy</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu bottom-menu w-120" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/research-and-policy/Current-research-focus">Current research focus</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/ResearchAndPolicies/Research">Research</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/research-and-policy/Pulse-polling-survey">Pulse polling surveys</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item padding-menu-bottom">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="http://ceda.com.au/Membership">Membership</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown padding-menu-bottom">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/Learning">CEDA Learning</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu bottom-menu w-185" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/Learning/Public-Policy-Dynamics">Public Policy Dynamics</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/Learning/Copland-Leadership-Program">Copland Leadership Program</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown padding-menu-bottom">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/EventsAndPrograms">Events and programs</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu bottom-menu w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" >Upcoming events</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" >Past events</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/ResearchAndPolicies/Research/Economy/environmental-social-and-governance">ESG Community</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown padding-menu-bottom">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/News-and-resources">News and resources</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu bottom-menu w-105" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/News">News</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/MediaReleases">Media release</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/Opinion">Opinion articles</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/Podcasts">Podcasts</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/MediaMentions">Media mentions</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/VideosAndPhotos">Videos and photos</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown padding-menu-bottom">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/About">About</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu bottom-menu w-105" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/About/Our-Story">Our Story</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/About/Our-People">Our People</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/About/Annual-reports">Annual Reports</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/SearchResult"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Mobile\tablet device navbar -->
            <div class="hidden-lg">
                <!--<div id="navbar" class="nav navbar-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true">-->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-unstyled ceda-nav-border pb-5">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Research and policy</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x cedaMenuCarot" role="button" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></i>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/research-and-policy/Current-research-focus">Current research focus</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/ResearchAndPolicies/Research">Research</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/research-and-policy/Pulse-polling-survey">Pulse polling surveys</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Membership</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">CEDA Learning</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x cedaMenuCarot" role="button" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></i>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/Learning/Public-Policy-Dynamics">Public Policy Dynamics</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/Learning/Copland-Leadership-Program">Copland Leadership Program</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Events and programs</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x cedaMenuCarot" role="button" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></i>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" >Upcoming events</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" >Past events</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/ResearchAndPolicies/Research/Economy/environmental-social-and-governance">ESG Community</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">News and resources</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x cedaMenuCarot" role="button" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></i>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu w-105" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/News">News</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/MediaReleases">Media release</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/Opinion">Opinion articles</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/Podcasts">Podcasts</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/MediaMentions">Media mentions</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/News-and-resources/VideosAndPhotos">Videos and photos</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">About</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x cedaMenuCarot" role="button" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></i>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu w-105" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/About/Our-Story">Our Story</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ceda.com.au/About/Our-People">Our People</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.ceda.com.au/About/Annual-reports">Annual Reports</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-unstyled ceda-nav-border">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#">Sign in</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x cedaMenuCarot" role="button" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></i>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu w-105" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My details</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My event registrations</a>
                        </div>
                        
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img class="join-ceda" src="i-ceda.svg">Join CEDA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img class="support-ceda" src="i-support.svg">Support us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg pr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contact</a>
                </ul>
                <!--</div>-->
            </div>
                
            </div>
        
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: logo is clickable for me either on desktop or mobile screen size

Comment: As i mentioned, the issue only occurs on Large screens - there's no issue on mobile display.  So with the Fiddle, expand the view so its al least 1222px wide - then you'll see the issue.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show some code here. It's not adequate to send us to other sites or post images.

Comment: Sorry... i added the code now

Answer (score 0):

I do think you have a container/row nesting issue, but without rewriting everything do this:

Change this:

```
<!-- Large screen Navbar -->
...
<div class="col-lg-12 col-12 small-row align-middle">
...
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-12 large-row align-middle">
...
</div>
```

To:

```
<!-- Large screen Navbar -->
...
<div class="col-lg-8 col-12 small-row align-middle pull-right">
...
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-12 large-row align-middle pull-right">
...
</div>
```

The only thing I changed is using smaller columns `col-lg-8` on the navbar containers and let them float right using the helper class `pull-right`, so they don't block your `<a href="#">` logo. I didn't touch your CSS in the provided fiddle.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14aprqby/)